# Can $('body') return an empty array?

Tags: jquery

Under what circumstances will $('body') find nothing ?

I was assuming this was impossible. Because there will always be a **body** element in the DOM tree.

However, I just fixed a bug that was due to exactly that. Some JS initialization code keeps a variable with a reference to the body element. In some cases this variable contained an empty jQuery wrapper.

Comment: One possibility could be If body is not added in DOM and $('body') executed.

Comment: Is there any other manipulation on that variable? Perhaps it's not the selector but rather changed made to the variable that holds the reference?

Comment: This is something like this: what to eat if I'm hungry? -> food, what to have if I am thrusty? -> water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of how this can happen is if you put the javascript in the `head` element, before the `body` has rendered.

The following document would display an alert saying

> $('body').length == 0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var b = $('body');
      alert("$('body').length == " + b.length);
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is why, in jquery, you usually do this:

```
$(function() {
   // Your code here
});
```

This idiom ensures your code runs after the page has loaded.

As another example, a slight alteration to the above code would display an alert saying

> $('body').length == 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        var b = $('body');
        alert("$('body').length == " + b.length);
      });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you not have that element on page (wrong code) or page not loaded complet...

Put your code in `$( document ).ready()`